# How long should I bake a hamburger meatloaf, and at what oven temperature?

Tags: baking, temperature, ground-beef, meatloaf

I invented my own recipe for meatloaf: hamburger, bread, 1 egg, dried onion bits, Worcestershire sauce, a bit of ketchup. Put into the oven at 350 degrees F.

Please advise the ideal oven temperature, and length of cooking time. Also, should I cover it with foil for part of the time?

Answer (score 5):

it will be cooked when it reaches the internal temperature corresponding to the "done" temperature of whatever meat you are using. From the [US food Safety Chart](http://www.foodsafety.gov/keep/charts/mintemp.html):

Category................................................Food.........................Temperature (°F)

Ground Meat & Meat Mixtures......Beef, Pork, Veal, Lamb.............160

Ground Meat & Meat Mixtures......Turkey, Chicken.......................165

I'd guess that it will take about 45min-75min depending on what size and shape of pan you are using. I personally don't cover my meatloaf with foil but I have a ketchup mixture I spread on the top so while that caramelizes it doesn't really "brown". If you have a "dry" top you may want to consider covering it, but I do find that covering with foil can increase the cooking time somewhat..

Comment: on the issue of a dry top ... see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10875/67

Answer (score 2):

Depending on depth and placement within the oven, 45-60 minutes most likely.

You'll have to test it, but once you know then you'll know.

Answer (score 0):

350 degrees for oven for around 40-45 minutes, I top mine with tomato sauce lightly and I cover mine with foil to keep it moist and remove foil the last 15 minutes